# Compare input string with space to an array using Bash

Tags: arrays, bash

I want to find a fastest way to compare between user input with a sorted array. Say I have an array like this

```
$ {arr[@]} = {Adam, Bob, Carl, Daniel}
```

And user input from terminal

```
$ Emma Carl Bob Frank
```

I want a comparision function that would print the equal value like

```
$ [ Carl, Bob ] already registerd
```

This is my current script which works only with 1 single input without space

```
containsElement () {
  local e
  for e in "${@:2}"; do [[ "$e" == "$1" ]] && return 1; done
  return 0
}

while true; do
  echo "Enter usernames, seperated by a space: "
  read USERNAMES
  containsElement "$USERNAMES" "${arr[@]}"
  var=$?
  if [ "$var" == '1' ]; then
    echo "User already exists!"
    break
  fi
done
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if this will be the "fastest," but here is one method that avoids the loop-within-a-loop:

```
arr=(Adam Bob Carl Daniel)
read -p "Enter usernames, separated by a space: " -a usernames
already=()
for name in "${usernames[@]}"
do
   [[ " ${arr[*]} " == *" $name "* ]] && already+=($name)
done
[ "${already[*]}" ] && echo "[ ${already[*]} ] already registered"
```

Example:

```
$ bash script.sh
Enter usernames, separated by a space: Emma Carl Bob Frank
[ Carl Bob ] already registered
```

#### Version with continuous loop

As per your request in the comments, this loops continuously.  I also had it update `arr` with the new names:

```
arr=(Adam Bob Carl Daniel)
while true
do
    read -p "Enter usernames, seperated by a space: " -a usernames
    already=()
    for name in "${usernames[@]}"
    do
       if [[ " ${arr[*]} " == *" $name "* ]]
       then
          already+=($name)
       else
          arr+=($name)
       fi
    done
    [ "${already[*]}" ] && echo "[ ${already[*]} ] already registered"
done
```

Comment: Thanks, it works, but I want to use a while loop to prompt for another input if any name exists

Comment: @Casper Yes, you can put a while loop around it.  I just added a version with a `while true` loop to the answer.

Comment: I added this code before your code prints the last statement to break out the loop if there is no existing name, would it work? `if [ -z "${already[*]}" ]; then break`

Comment: Almost: it needs and `fi`.  Try this:  `if [ -z "${already[*]}" ]; then break; fi`

Comment: this script works great, now is there anyway this script could somehow compare string regardless of case, ie, Adam == adam

Comment: @Casper Yes, use `shopt -s nocasematch`.

Comment: Thanks, it works perfectly. So this code affects the entire scope of my .sh file right?

Comment: very good.  And, no, not quite: it affects only the code that run __after__ the `shopt -s nocasematch` command.  So, to affect the whole script, make that command the first one in the script.

Comment: So is there anyway I could suppress/stop the effect after a certain lines?

Comment: Yes, to turn that off and return to case-sensitive matching, run `shopt -u nocasematch`.  (`-s` means to _set_ and option and `-u` means to _unset_ it.)  All commands run after that command will be case-sensitive again.  You can switch back and forth as often as you like.